# After migration Rails 6.0.34 -> 6.1 I can't use model inside the config/environments/development.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Rails 6.1.0 app:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[:password] = AppConfig::Mailchimp.api_key
```

*config/environments/development.rb*

```
module AppConfig
  class Mailchimp
    def self.api_key
     
      key = ENV['MAILCHIMP_API']
      # some additional processing here
      # ...
      key
    end
  end
end
```

*app/models/app_config/mailchimp.rb*

when trying to run dev console getting:

```
/config/environments/development.rb:59:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant AppConfig (NameError)
```

I'm after migration 6.0.3.4 -> 6.1 and it worked fine for the older Rails version.
Apparently they have changed way of loading things in new version, but I'm wondering:

1. Does anyone know the rationale of that change, any specific reason which brought Rails team to change that or it was not intentional.
2. How to fix it, I have at least 2 options:

   - `require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/app/app_config/mailchimp"` somewhere in the `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/development.rb`, but it doesn't look great as bypasses Rails way of booting app
   - using some built in way of loading config by https://www.rubydoc.org/github/rails/rails/master/ActiveSupport/ConfigurationFile

Comment: First and foremost, why is a config file inside the models folder, and why not pass the value as an ENV variable? You should never hardcode sensitive data.

Comment: totally agree @cesartalves, updated question - it takes value from env and does some processing with that value. I've used hardcoded value for ease but it's env indeed. Regarding keeping it models I don't have influence on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an initializer for setting up the mailer settings after the environment is loaded:

```
# config/initializers/custom_smtp.rb

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings.merge!({ password: AppConfig::Mailchimp.api_key })
```

Comment: Although it doesn't explain the reason it's much better than requiring things explicitly in environment files.

Answer (score 2):

Rails introduced the new [Zeitwerk autoloader](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk) and has been inching its' way into full adoption with Rails 6.  If you scan down to the bottom of the [Rails Configuration Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), you'll see there are two options available to you if you desire to keep the old way things worked:

```
config.load_defaults 6.0
config.autoloader = :classic
```

With those in place, your original code should continue to work.  However, from the example you gave, I urge you to consider using [Rails credentials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#environmental-security).  To do that, first run:

```
bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Add an entry for your Mailchimp API key:

```
mailchimp_api_key: abc1234
```

When you need to reference it, you just do:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings[:password] = Rails.application.credentials.mailchimp_api_key
```

Comment: Idea sounds very interesting but after checking it happens the same on the classic mode so must be different reason.